# Difference between vorteilhaft/günstig

Tags: difference

What is difference between "vorteilhaft" and "günstig"? Both mean that it is a good deal but I do not see the difference...

Comment: Please use a dictionary. Both have multiple meanings, and just one of them happens to be the same regarding deals...

Comment: @Torsten Link: The question isn't totally clear, but my interpretation is it's whether there is a difference (connotation/register/etc.) when the words refer to a transaction or purchase. A dictionary might not help with this; DWDS gives *günstig* as a meaning for *vorteilhaft* and vice versa.

Comment: @RDBury: When the question has more substance and specifics added, re-open may be considered. The restriction to *offers* (or similar) seems not to lead to different meaning in context, however. Cast in a single sentence I would say, that *vorteilhaft* (deliberately used in patents to describe lots of benefits) boils down to *better* (any kind of improvement), whereas *günstig* describes the total level achieved.

Comment: I would mirror translate it so: vorteilhaft -> advantageous (Vorteil = advantage), günstig = optimal, but it is a translation between two foreign languages.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica _günstig_ is no way _optimal_, _close to optimal_ at best.

Answer (score 2):

See the two words "Vorteil" and "Gunst" which are related to.

If the number of advantages is higher than the number of disadvantages, you can say "vorteilhaft" since the situation is more a "Vorteil" (engl.: advantage) for you.

If someone or something is affectionated to you, for instance when luck is on your side, the "Gunst" (engl.: favor) is with you and you can say "es ist günstig". A situation may be "günstig", if you have luck with all its circumstances or when someone/something helps you a bit.

In all cases a "günstig" situation is usually "vorteilhaft" for your life.

In the situation of buying things "vorteilhaft" means you have an advantage of the deal, and "günstig" means the circumstances are favorable to buy them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "affectionated to you"; can you rephrase?

Comment: @RDBury: devoted to